# Grails adding attributes to one-to-many relationship

Tags: grails

I have set up a one-to-many relationship in my scaffolded Grails application:

```
class Course {
    County county
    Date date
    int maxAttendance

    static hasMany = [ persons:Person ]
}

class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String email

    Course course

    boolean attended
    boolean paid

    static belongsTo = [ class:Course ]
}
```

So, when a user views the CourseController, they are able to see Person's registered in the selected Course.

My question is, how can I change the application so that when a user views the people in a given course, they can also view/modify the checkboxes for 'boolean attended' and 'boolean paid', which are also in the Person domain? Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that you are using the scaffolded view, so you are pretty much stuck with the default design.

You can modify the behaviour, by installing and modifying the templates that grails uses to generate those views:

```
grails install-templates
```

This will create the templates in `src/templates/scaffolding`, although I do not recommend that approach. Maybe it is time that you start developing your own controllers and views, since the scaffolding is there mainly for testing and for administrative use.

Comment: GalmWing, it looks like I will have to do that then. Thanks!